# What is the format for Stripe Connect access tokens?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to use stripe connect and I want to make sure that I'm receiving stripe access tokens that I can use to make charges on the behalf of Stripe users.  The access token I'm getting in my test environment looks like this:
sk_test_VyqtfZ6IIPMR1dyY0Po9O29i

Is this how they are formatted?  Is there a way I can do a test charge on this token?

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: No I was talking about stripe connect: https://stripe.com/connect

Comment: You might want to get your question as such

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me more like a `Test Secret Key`, an internal API key, rather than a card token.  To generate a card token you should be using the `createToken` function from Stripe's [JavaScript API](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).  Once you've done that you can pass that token instead of credit card details when creating a charge.  [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) is the relevant documentation from the API, and the part of interest:

> **card: optional**, *either card or customer is required, but not both*. A card to be charged. The card can either be a token, like the ones returned by Stripe.js, or a dictionary containing a user's credit card details

Depending on your specific needs you might consider taking a look at [Temboo's Stripe SDK](https://temboo.com/library/Library/Stripe/), it reduces the complexity of doing things like creating customers, charges, subscriptions, etc.  The free Temboo SDK is available in [many popular languages](https://temboo.com/download) and is a drop-in solution.

*Full disclosure: I'm a Temboo employee*